# Disabling and enabling button through jQuery but onclick event not trigerred after button enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem which I dont seem to find a solution for. The problem is this: I have some jQuery which will keep the button disabled until all the form's fields are filled up. When all the fields are filled up the button is being enabled, but the javascript onSubmit event used for the google recaptcha is not being trigerred. Anyone can help in this, please

Code is the one below:

```js
//jquery to disable button until all fields are filled up

$().ready(function() {
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#fbForm").validate({
        rules: {
         name: {
                required: true
            },
            surname: {
                required: true
            },
           
            terms: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return true;
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
  

        }
    });


    $('#fbForm').change(function() {
        if ($("#fbForm").valid()) {
            $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            
        }
    });
    
    
//recaptcha JS    
    function onSubmit(token) {
 if (screen.width >= 768) {
         document.getElementById("fbForm").submit();
 }else if (screen.width <= 767){
         document.getElementById("fbForm2").submit();
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="fbForm"class="well form-horizontal" action="winesOfDistinction.php?send=true" method="post" data-toggle="validator">

 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name "class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of First Name must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $name ;?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- Surname: Text input-->
    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="surname">Last Name</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="surname" id="surname" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of Last Name must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $surname ;?>" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group text-center">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
     
  <input type="checkbox" name="terms"id="terms" data-error="Please check the GDPR Disclaimercheck box in order to be able to submit the data" required>
        I agree
      </label>
      
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4"><br>
        <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" disabled="disabled" type="submit" value="" class="g-recaptcha btn btn-success" data-sitekey="6LfuAWcUAAAAAEKjLeOZfygAMxAeld1k4UUMGnfN" data-callback='onSubmit'>SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>

      </div>
    </div>
     </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: tried both, button remains disabled

Comment: I reread the question - you say that the button *does* become enabled, but there's a different issue, not to do with enabling the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a } at the last line to close the ready function. Fix that first.

Comment: closed the tag and tried freedomn-m's suggestions which were: $("#btnSubmit").prop( "disabled", false ); and $("#btnSubmit").attr('disabled', null); --still not working, kindly help please

Comment: There's no <fieldset> tag either which you are closing at the end. Just run the code in your local machine, find the errors in browser console and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$().ready(function() {
                    $('#num').validate();
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("fbForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            surname: {
                required: true
            },
           
            terms: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return true;
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
        

        }
    });


    $('#fbForm').change(function() {
        if ($("#fbForm").valid()) {
            $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            
        }
    });
    
    
//recaptcha JS    
    function onSubmit(token) {
    if (screen.width >= 768) {
         document.getElementById("fbForm").submit();
    }else if (screen.width <= 767){
         document.getElementById("fbForm2").submit();
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
       
<form name="formSend" id="fbForm" class="well form-horizontal" action="winesOfDistinction.php?send=true" method="post" data-toggle="validator">
    <fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name "class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
              <input type="text"  placeholder="First Name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of First Name must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $name ;?>" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            
            
            <!-- Surname: Text input-->
            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="surname">Last Name</label> 
                <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="surname" id="surname" class="form-control" data-minlength="2" data-error="Minimum Lenght of Last Name must be made up of at least 2 characters!" value="<?= $surname ;?>" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group text-center">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
             
          <input type="checkbox" name="terms"id="terms" data-error="Please check the GDPR Disclaimercheck box in order to be able to submit the data" required>
                I agree
              </label>
              
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
              <div class="col-md-4"><br>
                <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" disabled="disabled" type="submit" value="" class="g-recaptcha btn btn-success" data-sitekey="6LfuAWcUAAAAAEKjLeOZfygAMxAeld1k4UUMGnfN" data-callback='onSubmit'>SUBMIT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
    
              </div>
            </div>
             </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Okay, Missing jquery validtor and syntax errors were causing the problem. The snippet works fine.You should use visual code as editor and please resolve syntax errors before posting here.